# How to execute raw query in JPA?

Tags: postgresql, jpa

I'm trying to execute a raw query like this:

```
 em.createNativeQuery(
                "WITH RECURSIVE recursetree(id, parent_id) AS (\n" +
                "SELECT id, parent_g_id FROM group WHERE parent_g_id = 2\n" +
                "UNION\n" +
                "    SELECT t.id, t.parent_g_id\n" +
                "    FROM group t\n" +
                "    JOIN recursetree rt ON rt.id = t.parent_g_id\n" +
                "  )\n" +
                "SELECT * FROM recursetree;").getResultList();
```

On the Postgres side (via PGAdmin) it works fine, but from Java it get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

What do I do wrong? How to execute a really raw query on Postgres from a Java EE environment?

Comment: post the stack trace etc

Comment: Did you try to add a space after each `\n` character?

Comment: i'm solved this problem via another approach. thx all;

Comment: Seems like hibernate is incorrectly determining the type of one of the columns of the query result.